# How to check which condition was true in an if statement where the order matters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, conditional-statements

I know there are similar questions to this one but mine is sort of specific so I need some advice.

I am making a game in JS in which there are 4 divs racing, and the finish line is -70vw (racing right to left). They randomly increment their vw from 0 to 100 by 5-15 vw on button click. Right now what I have in my code to check the order of the winners is this:

```
 if (this.state.winnersArr.length < 4) {

  if (
    changePlayerArr[0].speed <= -70 &&
    !this.state.winnersArr.includes(changePlayerArr[0].name)
  ) {
    this.state.winnersArr.push(changePlayerArr[0].name);
  }
  if (
    changePlayerArr[1].speed <= -70 &&
    !this.state.winnersArr.includes(changePlayerArr[1].name)
  ) {
    this.state.winnersArr.push(changePlayerArr[1].name);
  }
  if (
    changePlayerArr[2].speed <= -70 &&
    !this.state.winnersArr.includes(changePlayerArr[2].name)
  ) {
    this.state.winnersArr.push(changePlayerArr[2].name);
  }
  if (
    changePlayerArr[3].speed <= -70 &&
    !this.state.winnersArr.includes(changePlayerArr[3].name)
  ) {
    this.state.winnersArr.push(changePlayerArr[3].name);
  }
  return changePlayerArr;
```

Here I have an array which pushes the div which passes -70vw which is the finish line. However since the checks for the div speed (changePlayerArr[0].speed) go from first div [0] to last div [3] if lets say the last div is at -69vw and the first at -65vw and on button click they both go to -70vw, the first div still ends up being first since the if check pushes it first to the winning array.

So I was wondering can I do something like this:

```
if(div[0].speed <= -70 || div[1].speed <= -70 || div[2].speed <= -70 || div[3].speed <= -70) 
 { // Check which statement was true in order and push to array}
```

But in this case the checks still go from left to right so I guess it wouldn't work either even if it was possible. Any suggestions? (Sorry if the explanation was a bit sucky i'm still new to this) :)

**EDIT: Perhaps it's not the way that I check the winners but the order in which I increment their speeds. Their increment should probably happen at the same time rather than from first div to last div, but the question still remains, how can I do that :/**

Comment: I think what you'll need to do is determine how far *past* -70vw each one goes.

Comment: @Pointy I thought of that but that shouldn't matter because ultimately if you have let's say only two divs racing and the second is at -69vw and the first at -60vw, even if they both come to exactly -70vw the second one should still win and the first one should be second.

Comment: I also thought of calculating the difference between the last speed value change between the divs to see who was first but that doesn't work either if they go beyond -70vw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having an if statement with a lot of conditions you could iterate the `changePlayerArr` like so:

```
this.state.winnersArr = changePlayerArr.map(player => {
  if(player.speed <= -70) {
    return player;
  }
});
```

With `map()` you can go through each player and return a new array with only the winners.
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Later you can then check which players are in the winners array.

If it's according to the speed property then you can [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the array like this:

```
this.state.winnersArr.sort((firstEl, secondEl) => {
 return firstEl.speed > secondEl.speed;
});
```

I hope that answers your question!

Comment: That does make the code simpler and I will implement that :) but I still don't get the correct order of the winners. If the second div is at -69vw and the first at -60vw for instance, even if they both get to -70vw on next click the first div still seems to win, even if it got slower to -70vw than the second one :/. I'm guessing the order of the mapping is the same as in the if statements

Comment: Yes, the order is according to the order or players. However you could sort the array according to the speed property. Check the [Array Sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method for that.